# Notation for subnet of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, notation

Let $X$ be a compact topological Space. Consider a nonconstant sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ such that $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an infinite subset of $X$. Note that the said sequence can be treated as a net from $\mathbb{N}$. Obviously, this sequence has a convergent subnet (which may not be a subsequence) in $X$. Now, I am finding it difficult to symbolise this subnet. I am trying to find a notation for this subnet which does not confuse it with subsequence. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What’s your definition of subnet ? There are several.

Comment: I am using the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet_(mathematics)#:~:text=In%20topology%20and%20related%20areas,generalize%20to%20nets%20as%20possible. Definition of subnet.

Comment: And see "Notes" on that page for the alternate definition.  Notation will be the same, regardless of which definition is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence.  A subnet is like this:  $J$ is a directed set, and for each $\alpha \in J$ we have an $n(\alpha) \in \mathbb N$.  The subnet is then $(x_{n(\alpha)})_{\alpha \in J}$.  [Some conditions are required, but they are not shown in the notation.]

This is similar to the subsequence notation $(x_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$.  But easier to read without a double subscript.